# Disadvantage of using a struct as a c "namespace"

Tags: c, struct, namespaces, global-namespace

I will often wrap a group of related global functions and variables in a struct that makes a kind of "namespace" for them, for example

```
extern struct foo_namespace {
    int (* const foo)(int a);
    int (* const bar)(void);
    const int a;
    const int b;
    int x;
    int y;
} foo;
```

Then link it with a `.c` file that sets the functions and constants.

This allows me to create global names without worrying about what's in the namespace and what will be later, it is very clean and convenient.

I do worry however that it introduces a small amount of inefficiency in my code by requiring the functions being called through pointers, and there may be other issues as well.

What are all of the potential problems and inefficiencies with grouping globals this way, whether they are problems with program design, speed, executable size, or anything else.

Edit:
I just ran a loop with an empty function in a struct, and a regular function. When no optimization was applied the function in the struct was faster (20 vs 26 seconds). After optimization, the global function was totally optimized away and was faster. It would seem that unless the function can be inlined it's not a big deal as far as speed goes

Comment: So why don't you program in C++? What is the point of the attempt to make C a pseudo OOL?

Comment: Just go with the flow and write idiomatic code. Deal with name clash issues when they arise. They almost never do.

Comment: @PeterJ Personally I just enjoy having more control and transparency in my program, and plus generally c creates smaller executables. However the c/c++ debate has occured many times before and I don't know that it's that important to discuss here

Comment: But you make your program not transparent and heavy to read. I had the same opinion when I started C++, ad trust me I would never touch C++ is it was less effective than C as I mainly do a bare metal embedded programming

Comment: Some overhead is unavoidable because the code have to resolve a reference each time at runtime. But thinking about your points I would suggest the use of preprocessor to move the overhead at compile time and avoid any loss of performance at runtime. I.e. defining a macro `#define ns(namespace, object) namespace##_##object` will prefix the object names with namespace and underscore with no work to do in the runtime.

Comment: @Frankie_C to make the the program even less transparent and more vulnerable? If someone writes in C - it should be C no C partially imitating something else.

Comment: If the function pointers are `const` and the compiler can see the definition (either from the same TU or via LTO), then there is no inefficiency. But I really hate it when people write C++ in C for political reasons.

Comment: The most significant problems with globals do not concern name collisions, but simply the scope and accessibility of such variables.  Your approach does nothing to address problems of that sort, and in that sense I don't consider it clean at all.

Comment: @JohnBollinger does this approach make those things more difficult? If so could you elaborate?

Comment: @PeterJ I get your point, but C preprocessor is  there also for things like that (and I’ve seen things you people wouldn’t believe...). Anyway in the case some differentiation is really required, and you can't switch to an OOL this can be a solution to reduce overhead.

Comment: @Frankie_C the solution is to program in C. Not C++ imitation.

Comment: @rtpax, your approach introduces complication without providing any clear benefit.  It does not worsen the problem with globals in any technical sense (that would be hard to accomplish), but to whatever extent it may appear to help in that area, it makes those problems worse by conveying a false sense of security to program developers and maintainers.

Comment: @rtpax `Personally I just enjoy having more control and transparency in my program, and plus generally c creates smaller executables.` You could write in C++ exactly as you did in C, but with namespaces. I'm sure there is a way to make the executable sizes similar.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I have looked into all the tricks I could find for shrinking size and the same code compiled with gcc has consistently been smaller than with g++. However, a debate between c and c++ is not the point of this question

Comment: @PeterJ I wouldn't be so tranchant. It is just an approximation of a missing feature. Avoids the bloat of all other parts that perhaps are not required as polymorphism, encapsulation, Inheritance, etc.

Comment: @Frankie_C It common opinion in the C world (I had exactly the same) about C++: _You wanted a banana but what you got was a gorilla holding the banana and the entire jungle._ But when you start to program the jungle becomes not as dense, dark and scary, you start to notice that is full of lovely tasty fruits and eventually you discover that the gorilla is a nice fellow who picks those fruits for you :). So to C or not to C - but not C as pseudo C++. Using C as pseudo C++ leads to unreadable, bad and buggy code

Comment: What is the problem with the `executable size`? I guess c++ executable  could be about 10 % (or less) bigger because of some additional protection and initialization/destruction code. Are you lacking disk space? BTW, in general in my experience c++ does better optimizations and runs faster than comparable c programs in many cases.

Answer (score 2):

More memory is allocated because of structure alignment (more info [here](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/)). A struct instance will have the alignment of its widest scalar member.

Comment: Detail: "have the alignment of its widest scalar member."  --> It is not the width of the members, it is the alignment needs of the members.  The link supports your point as a _generalization_, not a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

> Disadvantage of using a struct as a c “namespace”

Increase collision potential.

The idea here is to use `foo.a`, `foo.x` and `foo.bar()` vs. maybe `foo_a`,  `foo_x`, `foo_bar()`.  The trouble is now `foo` collides with any other 3 character `foo` object/function.

The prefix `foo_` approach takes a 5+ character match to collide.  [IOWs](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_other_words), although OP's idea does organize the objects and functions, it *increases* collisions chances.